# Labels on edges

Tags: tikz-pgf

For some reason, I can not have large labels on the edge. I get an overflow. Any idea? If I replace `$\{a_1, a_2\}$` with one character it works.

```
\begin{figure}[b]
   \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
     \SetUpEdge[lw         = 1pt,
                color      = black,
                labelcolor = white]
      \SetVertexNoLabel
      \GraphInit[vstyle=Normal] 
      \SetGraphUnit{3}
      \tikzset{VertexStyle/.append  style={fill}}
      \Vertex{s}
      \NO(s){a}  \EA(a){b} \SO(b){c}
      \Edge[label=$\{a_1, a_2\}$](s)(a)
      \Edge[label=$b$](a)(b)
      \Edge[label=$c$](b)(c)
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Graph $g_1$ \label{fig:graph_1}}
\end{figure}
```

The error that I get is:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\curr@fontshape ->\f@encoding
/\f@family /\f@series /\f@shape
l.38 \Edge[label=$\{a_1, a_2\}$](s)(a)
If you really absolutely need more capacity,
you can ask a wizard to enlarge me.
```

Comment: In a very simple manner, just add braces around your label: `{$\{a_1, a_2\}$}` will work.

Comment: Wow! So simple. It worked! Could you point me to docs in order to avoid similar questions in the future? The most relevant page that I have found is http://graphtheoryinlatex.blogspot.com/2009/08/several-options-for-edge-macro.html

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino You should add your comment as an answer.

Comment: @AlanMunn: do you think so? In an answer, I would like to motivate in detail the reason behind which just adding braces the error disappear. I think of knowing the motivation (token expansion?), but I believe of not being really able to explain clearly.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino It's helpful for the site to have answered questions, so even if you don't give an explanation, you've certainly helped with a solution.  Since this kind of issue is something that others might encounter,  a simple answer is well worth having.

Comment: The reason is the comma.  Without the braces, the comma is seen as a key-separator, so the label gets  `$\{a_1` as its argument, which causes all sorts of problems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error you got is due to the fact that the term `$\{a_1, a_2\}$` should be placed inside braces.

Indeed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[b]
   \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
     \SetUpEdge[lw         = 1pt,
                color      = black,
                labelcolor = white]
      \SetVertexNoLabel
      \GraphInit[vstyle=Normal] 
      \SetGraphUnit{3}
      \tikzset{VertexStyle/.append  style={fill}}
      \Vertex{s}
      \NO(s){a}  \EA(a){b} \SO(b){c}
      \Edge[label={$\{a_1, a_2\}$}](s)(a) % <= notice the modification
      \Edge[label=$b$](a)(b)
      \Edge[label=$c$](b)(c)
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Graph $g_1$ \label{fig:graph_1}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

will give you:

[image]